# Extended HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am a beginner in web development, and I have some misunderstanding.

From wwwschools:

```
AngularJS extends HTML with new attributes.
```

So angularJS uses for example `ng-model`, `ng-app` and so on.
My questions are

1. Why does AngularJS does this, when adding custom attributes makes the HTML invalid?
2. Can I add my own attribute like `<h myAttr="hello">` and then access it with JS just like a normal attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't add them by itself. It allows you to use some custom attributes, like `ng-model` to deal with its functional stuff, but you have to set them by yourself.

And if using non-standard attributes bothers you, you can replace them by `data-*` valid attributes, like `data-ng-model="stuff"`.

Finally, adding your own custom attributes (generally called directives in Angular) is often use. You can check [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for a hint on how you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why does AngularJS does this, when adding custom attributes makes the HTML invalid?

The idea is that you can write your own custom self-contained elements that better explain what their purpose is. For example, instead of:

```
<div class="date-picker" data-initial="2015-08-08"></div>
```

you can write:

```
<date-picker value="2015-08-08" />
```

which is more self-explanatory than a plain `<div>` with a special marker CSS class.

Of course this wouldn't just work out of the box, you would have to define this new date picker element by writing an [Angular directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

> 2. Can I add my own attribute like  and then access it with JS just like a normal attribute?

Yes, you can, by writing a new *directive* (see above).